# DAX - Measures to count distinct status and group by max date and multiple fields or group key

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to write multiple DAX expressions to summarize a transaction dataset. The combination of [Manufacturer] and [PartNo] will determine uniqueness so those fields need to be grouped together. I can also concatenate the 2 fields together and create a composite key ([ManufacturerPartKey]) if its easier grouping data that way.

MyTable sample data:

```
 Manufacturer  PartNo     TxDate     TxStatus      ErrorCode     ManufacturerPartKey
 ABC             123    9/29/2020   Fail         CodeInvalid     ABC-123
 ABC             123    9/30/2020   Fail         CodeInvalid     ABC-123
 ABC             123    10/1/2020   Success      null            ABC-123
 ABC             789    10/1/2020   Fail         PartInvalid     ABC-789   
 ABC             567    10/1/2020   Success      null            ABC-567
 XYZ             567    9/29/2020   Fail         LoadFail        XYZ-567
 XYZ             567    9/30/2020   Fail         LoadFail        XYZ-567
 XYZ             789    10/1/2020   Fail         APIFault        XYZ-789
 LMO             456    9/29/2020   Fail         APIFault        LMO-456
 LMO             456    9/30/2020   Fail         APIFault        LMO-456
 EFG             123    10/1/2020   Success      null            EFG-123
 QRS             123    10/1/2020   Fail         PartInvalid     QRS-123
 QRS             123    10/2/2020   Fail         PartInvalid     QRS-123
 QRS             123    10/3/2020   Fail         PartInvalid     QRS-123
 QRS             123    10/4/2020   Fail         PartInvalid     QRS-123
 QRS             567    10/4/2020   Success      null            QRS-567
```

Requirements:

1. Count of distinct combinations of Manufacturer + Part No

   ```
    Expected Output = 9
   ```
2. Count of Success

   ```
    Expected Output = 4
   ```
3. Count of "outstanding" failures by [Manufacturer] and [PartNo] or [ManufacturerPartKey] and max
   TxDate

   ```
    Expected Output = 5
   ```

Answer:

```
            CountFailure =
            VAR _maxDate =
                TREATAS (
                    ADDCOLUMNS (
                        VALUES ( MyTable[ManufacturerPartKey] ),
                        "maxDate", CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'MyTable'[TxDate] ) )
                    ),
                    MyTable[GroupKey],
                    MyTable[TxDate]
                )
            RETURN
                CALCULATE (
                    COUNTROWS ( SUMMARIZECOLUMNS ( MyTable[ManufacturerPartKey], MyTable[TxStatus], _maxDate ) ),
                    MyTable[TxStatus] = "Failure"
                )
```

4. Count of reprocessed (ABC-123 was submitted 3 times and was re-processed on the 3rd attempt)

   ```
           1
   ```
5. Count of distinct error codes by max TxDate

   ```
       ErrorCode        Count
       CodeInvalid       0    
       APIFault          2
       LoadFail          1
       PartInvalid       2
       Null              4
   ```

Expected Summary Table Output:

```
Manufacturer TotalSubmissions  TotalFailed  TotalSucceeded  DistinctPartNoCount  OutstandingFailures ReprocessedCount 
 ABC           5                3           2               3                    1                   1
 XYZ           3                3           0               2                    2                   0
 LMO           2                2           0               1                    2                   0
 EFG           1                0           1               1                    0                   0
 QRS           5                4           1               2                    0                   0
```

***EDIT***

New Sample with duplicates:

```
   Manufacturer  PartNo     TxDate     TxStatus      ErrorCode     ManufacturerPartKey

  ABC             123    9/29/2020   Fail         CodeInvalid     ABC-123
  ABC             123    9/30/2020   Fail         CodeInvalid     ABC-123
  ABC             123    10/1/2020   Success      null            ABC-123
  ABC             123    10/1/2020   Fail         DuplicatePart   ABC-123
  ABC             789    10/1/2020   Fail         PartInvalid     ABC-789   
  ABC             567    10/1/2020   Success      null            ABC-567
  ABC             567    10/2/2020   Fail         null            ABC-567
  XYZ             567    9/29/2020   Fail         LoadFail        XYZ-567
  XYZ             567    9/30/2020   Success      null            XYZ-567
  XYZ             567    9/30/2020   Fail         DuplicatePart   XYZ-567
  XYZ             789    10/1/2020   Fail         APIFault        XYZ-789
  XYZ             789    10/1/2020   Fail         APIFault        XYZ-789
  LMO             456    9/29/2020   Fail         APIFault        LMO-456
  LMO             456    9/30/2020   Fail         APIFault        LMO-456
  LMO             555    10/1/2020   Fail         APIFault        LMO-555
  EFG             123    10/1/2020   Success      null            EFG-123
  QRS             123    10/1/2020   Fail         PartInvalid     QRS-123
  QRS             123    10/2/2020   Fail         PartInvalid     QRS-123
  QRS             123    10/3/2020   Success      null            QRS-123
  QRS             123    10/3/2020   Fail         PartInvalid     QRS-123
  QRS             123    10/4/2020   Fail         PartInvalid     QRS-123
  QRS             567    10/4/2020   Success      null            QRS-567
  QRS             567    10/5/2020   Fail         DuplicatePart   QRS-567
  QRS             222    10/5/2020   Fail         APIFault        QRS-222
  QRS             222    10/6/2020   Success      null            QRS-222
  QRS             222    10/6/2020   Success      null            QRS-222
```

New Summary Table Output:

```
 Manufacturer TotalSubmissions  TotalFailed  TotalSucceeded  DistinctPartNoCount  OutstandingFailures ReprocessedCount 

  ABC           6                4           2               3                    1                   1
  XYZ           5                4           1               2                    1                   1
  LMO           3                3           0               2                    2                   0
  EFG           1                0           1               1                    0                   0
  QRS           10               6           4               3                    1                   2
```

Note:

1. If there is at least 1 failure and 1 success per ManufacturerPartKey, it should be Reprocessed = 1. The count should not increment even if there are duplicates. For QRS-567, there is 1 success and 1 failure but it shouldn't count as Reprocessed = 1 because the 1st time it loaded it was already successful. QRS-123 and QRS-222 have duplicates but are the two "reprocessed" PartNos for QRS.
2. If there is at least 1 failure and 0 success, it should be Outstanding Failure = 1. The Outstanding Failures count should not match total failures.

I understand these requirements are challenging given the imperfect dataset but that's what I have to work with. Go me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to calculate in "OutstandingFailures" (put this code in new Table on DATA tab in powerbi:

```
OutputTable =
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    Manufactur[Manufacturer],
    "TotalSubmissions", COUNTROWS ( Manufactur ),
    "TotalFailed",
        CALCULATE (
            COUNTROWS ( Manufactur ),
            FILTER ( ALL ( Manufactur[TxStatus] ), Manufactur[TxStatus] = "Fail" )
        ),
    "TotalSucceeded",
        CALCULATE (
            COUNTROWS ( Manufactur ),
            FILTER ( ALL ( Manufactur[TxStatus] ), Manufactur[TxStatus] = "Success" )
        ),
    "DistinctPartNoCount", CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( Manufactur[PartNo] ) ),
    "OutstandingFailures",
        VAR _maxDate =
            TREATAS (
                ADDCOLUMNS (
                    VALUES ( Manufactur[ManufacturerPartKey] ),
                    "maxDate", CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Manufactur'[TxDate] ) )
                ),
                Manufactur[ManufacturerPartKey],
                Manufactur[TxDate]
            )
        RETURN
            CALCULATE (
                COUNTROWS ( Manufactur ),
                FILTER ( ALL ( Manufactur[TxStatus] ), Manufactur[TxStatus] = "Fail" ),
                _maxDate
            ),
    "ReprocessedCount",
        VAR _failure =
            SELECTCOLUMNS (
                FILTER (
                    ALL ( Manufactur[ManufacturerPartKey], Manufactur[TxStatus] ),
                    Manufactur[TxStatus] = "Fail"
                ),
                "Key", Manufactur[ManufacturerPartKey]
            )
        RETURN
            CALCULATE (
                COUNTROWS ( Manufactur ),
                FILTER ( ALL ( Manufactur[TxStatus] ), Manufactur[TxStatus] = "Success" ),
                _failure
            )
)
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried this code and using a calculated table seems like a very good solution for my requirement! Let me clarify that outstanding failures is the count of transaction failures that have not yet been re-processed into "success" transaction by ManufacturerPartKey. For example, ABC manufacturer has 3 total failures but only 1 outstanding failure. The outstanding failure is ABC-789 because the most recent ABC-789 transaction on 10/1/2020 is a failure. As for ABC-123 and ABC-567, we don't count any previously failed transactions so long as the most recent one is a success. Does that make sense?

Comment: I also want to add that manufacturer ABC has a reprocessed count of 1 because ABC-123 failed twice but succeeded on the third transaction, therefore it was re-processed. A reprocessed transaction is any transaction that has failed but re-tried and was successful.

Comment: I suppose my previous DAX formula to calculate Outstanding Failures won't work because "SummarizeColumns() may not be used in this context". Is there another way to re-write this measure for the calculated table to count only the most recent transactions that ended with a TxStatus of Failure by ManufacturerPartKey?

Comment: In my answer you have ReprocessedCount, and it is show only 1 for ABC;
If I have good understanding how you want to calculate OutstandingFailures then-current answer is ok?
1 QRS, 1ABC, 1LMO, 2XYZ ??

Comment: Your answer seems perfect for the sample data, however, when I plugged the query into my project it seems like the calculations for DistinctPartCount, outstanding failures, and reprocessed is not quite correct. Outstanding Failures is way off and for Reprocessed its showing the same numbers as TotalSucceeded.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problems with other sample data?

Comment: I reproduced the dataset to better reflect my environment. I believe your calculated table works fine but I need to fix the outstanding failure count, distinct partNo count, and Reprocessed count. I believe if there is at least 1 success or 1 failure, it should count as reprocessed = 1. For outstanding failure, if there is at least 1 failure and 0 success, it should count as outstanding failure = 1.